# Woocommerce Logout/How to make custom logout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, logout

I would like to make a logout feature on my webpage.  How can I do this when the user is only logged in have a logout feature adn successfully logout?  Is there a plugin or something or some code I can insert somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
 include 'config.php';
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = false;
 $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = false;   
 $_SESSION['username']=false;
 session_destroy();   
 header("Location:index.php");
```

Comment: What does this do?  Where do I put this?

Comment: create a logout.php file and add a button into your webpage and redirect to logout.php also if it will work rate my post :) like to help you.

Comment: Can you write a list for me like detailed.  I think I know what you are saying but I dunno.

Like:
1. //This is step 1
2. //This is step 2

Thanks

Comment: step1 create a button in your page which will redirect you to logout.php                     Step 2 create a logout.php file and put the above code there and save it done.

Comment: How do I create that file in wordpress and under which folder

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create logout link

Step2: check the session variable for this link show it only if session exist

step3: click on logout

```
 function logout(){
          session_destroy();
          header("Location:login.php");
        }
```